# database connected but not responding as expected when queried

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, doctrine-orm

I have a database online that has been running fine with my application until yesterday when it started to behave strangely.

For example when a user does an operation that inserts data into my database(db), I was able to see the changes when I logged in as the admin.

Now a client inserts data into my db but when I want to view that from the application, nothing is displayed but insertion is actually made on db.

I thought my database crashed but when I check my db it shows all tables are OK.

To debug the app I downloaded the app and the same db to work on it locally, but the same app and db works smoothly and as expected locally.

The app is developed **Codeigniter 2.1.4** framework and I used **doctrine 1.2.1** to create db tables and most queries are done using this doctrine helper.

My online server runs on **PHP version 5.4** and **MYSQL version 5.5** while the local server has **PHP version 5.5** and **MYSQL version 5.6**.

What really might be the problem here?

Comment: Can you check the connection parameter for the database?

Comment: @AmithRajShetty if the connection parameters were wrong could client's inserted data be reflected on the db? I don't think so

Comment: There might be a case where you are using a different connection to write to database and a different one to read, I was guessing that might be the case with you.

Comment: @AmithRajShetty I have just one connection instance

Comment: okay. Sounds weird. probably a caching issue?

Comment: Obviously not a real solution. But have you tried updating your installations? PHP is now in 7 and only the local server had the current most recent MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 0):

Checklist:

1. Are you connected to the right db?
2. Can you demonstrate from the server logs that the request hit the web server?
3. Can you show that the connection and queries make it to the database?
4. Are you opening transactions and forgetting to commit them?

If that doesn't fix the problem then look into what changed recently (source control software like git,hg, or svn can help here).